# Excel 2013 - Group rows by column value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

How do I group rows by column value in Excel 2013, like how you see in a SharePoint list?

For example, if this is my table:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4
-----------------------------
1001  | 1002  | 1003  | 1004
2001  | 2002  | 2003  | 1004
3001  | 3002  | 3003  | 2004
4001  | 4002  | 4003  | 2004
```

And I group by Col 4, I would like to see the result like this:

```
Col 4 = 1004

  Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 
  -----------------------
    1001  | 1002  | 1003
    2001  | 2002  | 2003

Col 4 = 2004

  Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 
  -----------------------
    3001  | 3002  | 3003
    4001  | 4002  | 4003
```

Is this at all possible in Excel?  I tried creating a pivot table but it just creates nested rows, not the view I'm looking for.

Anyone out there who can help?

Comment: Use the filter?

Comment: @Scott Craner If you're referring to Row Label filter, I can see only results for one grouping value at a time.  How do I see all values, grouped by the grouping criteria?

Comment: Pivot Table Filters. Build a pivot table, throw those first three columns in the"Columns" of the pivot and then filter Column 4, in the pivot table selection. You can also add a Slicer on Column 4 and then just click on the value you want to filter by.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph ;) I tried pivot table, but what's happening is that Col 2 gets nested under Col 1, and Col 3 gets nested under Col 2 -- if I put my columns in ROWS area of pivot table.  And if I put them in the COLUMNS area, I just get pivot table columns for all possible values in that column.  You see what I'm saying?

Comment: @JNevill I feel like I have done a poor job explaining my problem.  Because I tried what you suggested, and the result is not even close to where I'd like to be.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone suggested, use **`PivotTable`**. Here I've added helper column in the beginning, you can hide that column if you want to.

[image]

Use filter in cell `B12` to select other value.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!  Here's the problem though.  The values in my columns A, B, C, D are not numbers, they are text.  And when they are text, the values in the pivot table change from the values to actual row counts and sums.  Try changing the values in your column C to w, x, y, z or something, and you'll know what I'm saying.  Do you know how to get around that problem?

Comment: any update? Only want to show the rows themselves instead of sums, max, min, etc